# How to solve $\log_2(x) +3 = \log_3(x+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, problem-solving

Hi Math Stack Exchange Communities,
I am new here. I have a question regarding logarithm solving.

Let's say I have this equation:

$$\log_2 (x) +3 = \log_3 (x+2)$$

How can I solve this kind of equation?

Thank you!

Comment: It needs some formatting. For example, are the bases of the logs $2$ and $3$ respectively?

Comment: Besides the bases, are the logarithms on $\;x\;$ alone or on $\;x+3\;$ , etc.? For example, is left side $\;\log_2x+3\;$ or $\;\log_2(x+3)\;$ > Please use parentheses! Even better: learn the easy steps to use MathJax as this site requires.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I misunderstood it due to its original title. I removed my comments.

Comment: I think as first step you can convert both logrithms to have same base. Then may be we can write the equation in the form $10^{\frac{3l}{k}}x=(x+2)^{\frac{m}{k}}$ where $l, m, k$ are constants. I assumed the conversion is to base 10 logrithm.

Comment: we have:
$$\log_{2} x + \log_{2} 2^{3} =\log_{3} (x+2)$$
and then we replace in the original equation
$$\log_{2} (8x)=\log_{3} (x+2)$$
for properties of logarithms, we have:
$$\log_{2} (8x)=\frac{\log_{2} (x+2)}{\log_{2}3}$$
$$\log_{2} (8x)\cdot \log_{2} 3=\log_{2} (x+2)$$
$$\log(8x)^{\log_{2}3}=\log_{2}(x+2)$$
$$(8x)^{\log_{2} 3}=x+2$$
$$27x^{\log_{2}3}-x-2=0$$  and this equation don't have solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to natural logarithms, the function you look the zero for write$$f(x)=\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}-\frac{\log (x+2)}{\log (3)}+3$$ Its derivative $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x \log (2)}-\frac{1}{(x+2) \log (3)}$$ would cancel for $x=\frac{2 \log (3)}{\log (2)-\log (3)}<0$ and you could easily show that $f'(x) >0$ for all $x>0$.

If $x\to 0$, $f(x)\to -\infty$ and by inspection $f(1)=2$; so, there is a root between $0$ and $1$.

At this point, we need some numerical method and Newton would probably be the simplest to use. The problem is that, starting with $x_0=1$ will give a first iterate which will be negative (outside the acceptable range). Plotting the function would be the simplest way the locate more or less accurately the root. Otherwise, let us tabulate some values 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & f(x) \\
 0.1 & -0.997269 \\
 0.2 & -0.039613 \\
 0.3 & +0.504888 \\
 0.4 & +0.881186 
\end{array}\right)$$

So, let us use $x_0=0.2$. Newton iterates will then be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0.2058256595809923861 \\
 2 & 0.2059161927467302404 \\
 3 & 0.2059162137902695078 \\
 4 & 0.2059162137902706441 
\end{array}
\right)$$